# Can I call initstate in each dropdown value changed

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter application is have set of dropdown values. In every dropdown value changed that time. i want to work initstate method. Is it possible? if yes please provide any details.

```
  onChanged: (val) {
                      log(val.toString());
                        value.dropDownMethod(val.toString());
                    }),
```

This is actually drop down method..

```
 void getLIstItems(String query) {
_listItems = cameraDetails
    .where((element) => element["location"]["name"] == query)
    .toList();
log(_listItems.toString());
 }
```

This "_listItems" return a list in every dropdown is changed..
So i want update the value in inistate method in every drop value is changed..how it possible?

```
            @override
        void initState() {
        super.initState();

BetterPlayerConfiguration betterPlayerConfiguration =
    BetterPlayerConfiguration(
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        autoDetectFullscreenDeviceOrientation: true);
BetterPlayerDataSource dataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
    BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network, widget.cameraDetails!["live_url"]);
_betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(betterPlayerConfiguration);

_betterPlayerController.setupDataSource(dataSource);
 }
```

This is the iniState method, I want to chnage  the "widget.cameraDetails!["live_url"])", every dropdown value chnaged..it possible? Please provide any solution,please support

Comment: You need to show your code and explain why  you think you need to run initState on each dropdown value change.

Comment: can you describe more about what do you want to achieve so we can help

Comment: I updated the question. Let me please share how to solve this..